# FindFit returns "tensors have incompatible shapes"

Tags: tensors, fitting

I'm trying to fit experimental data with FindFit and implicitly calculated function. It seems, that function works fine and satisfactorily approximates data when parameters are fed manually. However when trying to apply FindFit with the same set of parameters as starting values, it returns "Tensors {..1..} and {..2..} have incompatible shapes". These tensors are equal. Manual calculation shows, that their elements are differences between experimental and fitted values (for starting values of parameters) for each experimental point. Thus by multiplying them, FindFit probably tries to calculate the sum of squared residuals.
If above is correct, why does this error emerge? I tried substituting the fitting function with simple second-order polynomial and it works.
Here is the code:

```
Remove["Global`*"]    
Hk = 952.45844; Rahe = 815; const = 797; AngCr = 
     54.35 \[Degree]; Ang = 45 \[Degree];
    a[b_?NumericQ] := ArcSin[Tan[b]/Tan[AngCr] ];
    NewH[b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, Ang_?NumericQ, Hamp_?NumericQ] := 
      Flatten[({
          {Cos[c], -Sin[c], 0},
          {Sin[c], Cos[c], 0},
          {0, 0, 1}
         }).({
          {Cos[b], 0, Sin[b]},
          {0, 1, 0},
          {-Sin[b], 0, Cos[b]}
         }).({
          {1, 0, 0},
          {0, Cos[a[b]], -Sin[a[b]]},
          {0, Sin[a[b]], Cos[a[b]]}
         }).({
          {Hamp*Cos[Ang \[Degree]]},
          {Hamp*(-Sin[Ang \[Degree]])},
          {0}
         })];
    (* Implicit fitting function: *)
    Rfit[b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, Ang_?NumericQ, Hamp_?NumericQ, 
      Rphe_?NumericQ] := 
     Rahe*Sin[theta] - 
       Rphe*Cos[theta]^2*
        Abs[(NewH[b, c, Ang, Hamp][[1]]*NewH[b, c, Ang, Hamp][[2]])/(
         NewH[b, c, Ang, Hamp][[1]]^2 + NewH[b, c, Ang, Hamp][[2]]^2)] + 
       const /. 
      Quiet@NSolve[
        Tan[theta] == (Hk*Sin[theta] + NewH[b, c, Ang, Hamp][[3]])/Sqrt[
          NewH[b, c, Ang, Hamp][[1]]^2 + NewH[b, c, Ang, Hamp][[2]]^2] && 
         theta <= Pi/2 && theta > 0.5, theta, Reals]
    FindFit[ExpData, 
     Rfit[b, c, Ang, Hamp, 
      Rphe], {{b, 0, -0.1, 0.1}, {c, 0, -0.1, 0.1}, {Rphe, 450, 400, 
       500}}, Hamp]

    (* Manual approximation works fine: *)
    Show[
     ListPlot[
      Parallelize[
       Table[Flatten[{Hamp, 
          Rfit[-2.5 \[Degree], 0 \[Degree], 45, Hamp, 465]}], {Hamp, -401,
          401, 10}]], PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]}],
     ListPlot[ExpData, PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[5]}],
     PlotRange -> All
     ]
```

Here is the piece of experimental data:

```
ExpData = {{-377.4285`, 1503.685`}, {-366.8757`, 
    1509.651`}, {-357.7828`, 1514.686`}, {-347.0045`, 
    1520.59`}, {-338.1022`, 1525.638`}, {-327.2154`, 
    1530.05`}, {-318.4717`, 1534.859`}, {-307.7064`, 
    1539.4`}, {-299.1506`, 1543.492`}, {-288.0877`, 
    1548.19`}, {-279.8359`, 1552.482`}, {-268.8763`, 
    1557.043`}, {-260.4716`, 1560.633`}, {-249.6292`, 
    1563.926`}, {-240.9715`, 1567.46`}, {-230.3227`, 
    1570.869`}, {-220.9978`, 1573.732`}, {-209.8838`, 
    1578.208`}, {-202.0967`, 1580.598`}, {-191.8868`, 
    1583.704`}, {-181.9674`, 1586.1`}, {-172.2505`, 
    1588.278`}, {-162.1441`, 1591.064`}, {-152.7795`, 
    1592.871`}, {-142.4023`, 1594.542`}, {-133.2651`, 
    1597.427`}, {-125.6026`, 1597.731`}, {-113.7561`, 
    1601.733`}, {-103.0388`, 1603.187`}, {-94.00935`, 
    1604.345`}, {-83.34793`, 1605.78`}, {-74.33023`, 
    1606.449`}, {-63.44335`, 1608.238`}, {-54.81877`, 
    1608.54`}, {-44.04633`, 1608.988`}, {-35.41862`, 
    1610.753`}, {-24.58675`, 1610.793`}, {-17.20935`, 
    1610.65`}, {-5.281529`, 1612.059`}, {2.261039`, 
    1610.745`}, {13.69646`, 1611.337`}, {23.07399`, 
    1611.651`}, {33.15822`, 1609.854`}, {43.12982`, 
    1609.793`}, {52.70468`, 1608.815`}, {62.87678`, 
    1608.523`}, {72.25062`, 1607.767`}, {82.43324`, 
    1606.551`}, {91.69639`, 1605.46`}, {97.61601`, 
    1601.687`}, {111.4225`, 1602.904`}, {121.9307`, 
    1601.799`}, {130.9983`, 1599.582`}, {141.4585`, 
    1598.096`}, {150.7068`, 1595.881`}, {161.252`, 
    1593.875`}, {170.2011`, 1591.611`}, {180.8177`, 
    1588.666`}, {189.7459`, 1585.693`}, {200.3986`, 
    1583.918`}, {209.3968`, 1581.302`}, {219.8005`, 
    1578.068`}, {227.8856`, 1574.321`}, {239.7572`, 
    1571.973`}, {249.5857`, 1568.514`}, {259.3328`, 
    1565.229`}, {269.4772`, 1561.71`}, {279.0915`, 
    1558.152`}, {289.2914`, 1553.891`}, {298.7476`, 
    1549.908`}, {308.9017`, 1545.625`}, {318.3074`, 
    1541.339`}, {328.4131`, 1536.248`}, {337.7596`, 
    1532.195`}, {347.9528`, 1528.05`}, {357.3661`, 
    1522.416`}, {367.6034`, 1517.481`}, {377.0643`, 1512.4`}};
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Note, that you require solutions that are `Reals`. If for your parameter set or during the fitting procedure no real  solution is found, this will probably result in a problem down the road. This might cause your incompatible tensors.

Comment: Also note that you give `Ang` in degrees already, but later define a function using `Ang Degree`. This is probably not wanted and in general dangerous causing many errors difficult to find. Try not to use a degree conversion inside your functions, but only on function call, i.e. on parameter definition.

Comment: @mikuszefski thanks for the `Degree` comment, missed it, now it's fixed. As for `Reals`, I believe it's OK, because I tuned the `Rfit` function so that it returns exactly one real value (for sets of parameters, which are experimentally reasonable).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some errors corrected and a few tricks

- Using memoization,
- "Precomputing" the solutions by using Reduce    once  instead  of NSolve each time,
- Rewriting the  functions in a compact and more understandable way,
- Reducing the overall calcs needed,
- Using NonlinearModelFit with Method ->    {"NMinimize", Method ->
  "NelderMead"} for efficiency
- Reduced    the ConfidenceLevel for an additional speedup

:

```
Hk = 952.45844; Rahe = 815; const = 797; AngCr = 54.35 °; Ang = 45 °;
a[b_] := ArcSin[Tan[b]/Tan[AngCr]];
red = Quiet@Reduce[Tan[t] == (Hk*Sin[t] + bb)/cc && cc > 0, t, Reals] /. C[1] -> 0;
rt[b_, c_] := First@Select[t/. {red/. {bb-> b, cc-> c}//N//ToRules}, 1/2<#<Pi/2 &]

rid = Reverse@IdentityMatrix@3;
NewH[b_, c_, w_, Hamp_] := NewH[b, c, w, Hamp] =
  Hamp Evaluate[Dot@@MapThread[RotationMatrix, {{c, b, a@b}, rid}].{Cos@w,-Sin@w,0}]

Rfit[b_?NumericQ, c_, Ang_, Hamp_?NumericQ, Rphe_] := Rfit[b, c, Ang, Hamp, Rphe] =
  Module[{v = NewH[b, c, Ang, Hamp], sq, t},
   sq = v[[1]]^2 + v[[2]]^2;
   t = rt[v[[3]], Sqrt@sq];
   Rahe*Sin[t] - Rphe*Cos[t]^2*Abs[v[[1]] v[[2]]/sq] + const]
```

Now:

```
k = NonlinearModelFit[ExpData, {Rfit[b, c, Ang, Hamp, Rphe], 
                     -.1 < b < .1 && -.1 < c < .1 && 400 < Rphe < 500}, 
                       {b, c, Rphe}, Hamp, 
                       Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "NelderMead"}, 
                       ConfidenceLevel -> .5]
```

A fair fit:

```
ListLinePlot@k[{"Response", "PredictedResponse"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The parameters:

```
k["BestFitParameters"]
(* {b -> -0.0471051, c -> 0.1, Rphe -> 499.547}*)
```

You may (or may not) get better results by increasing the confidence level at the expense of more calc time.

Comment: To simplify even further, note the `NewH[]` function is basically a coordinate transformation of a vector. You can remove the `Flatten[]` and the inner braces in the last vector.

Comment: The main error, I guess was the fact that the function returned `{value}`, which you corrected by `First[]`. With this adjustment `FindFit[]` should work as well, right? Moreover, this makes it a error due to erroneous function definition and not a `FindFit` problem. This is already suggested by the error message when running the original post. Finally, looking at the boundary conditions of @Alexander, one also has to notice that `c` and `Rphe` are on the limit here, rendering the result questionable (Not from the answer point of view, but from the physics point of view...just saying).

Comment: @mikuszefski the main issue was calc time. I massaged the fitting procedure until it spitted out something in a few minutes.

Comment: @mikuszefski Regarding the "edge values" for the parameters, I really don't know. Without a deeper understanding of the physics it's impossible to say if those intervals are right

Comment: Nice answer & speed-up, +11

Comment: I agree that this evaluates slowly and speeding it up is a nice bonus. Nevertheless, the original question on `FindFit` is actually a "made a mistake in my function definition", i.e. the return value has been a list instead of a single value. Concerning the boundaries and the physics, I guess we are talking about planar and anomalous Hall effect. `b` and `c` seem to rotate a field (x-y-z Euler angle) and `Rphe` is the value of the planar Hall effect. Sure we can't say why the angles and `Rphe` should have this limits. However, `c` and `Rphe`  taking the limits, tells me that something is odd.

Comment: @belisarius, thank you very much for the prompt and very useful reply! I believe (as @mikuszefski mentioned) that the key issue was that function returned `{value}`. I added `First[]` to `FindFit` and it also started working. Strangely I've never had this problem in previous fitting (different type of data, but same program structure).

Comment: @mikuszefski, as for the physical part. Yes, we are talking about planar and anomalous Hall effects. b and c are misalignment angles between planes of external field and a sample (the third degree of freedom is determined experimentally, no need to fit it). Angles are limited as they are not bigger than 5 deg. Rphe is limited for purposes of algorithm debugging with Rahe and manual fit as reference points.
p.s. don't think that removing `Flatten[]` is a good idea, see my first question

Comment: @Alexander. You have `matrix.matrix.matrix.vector`. In your case you need the `Flatten[]` because you defined the vector as `{{vx},{vy},{vy}}`. There is no reason for this. If you just define it as  `{vx, vy, vy}` you don't need to flatten.

Comment: @Alexander Finally, to speed up even more, notice that you calculate `NewH[]` 7 times with the same set of parameters. By calling it once and saving the result in a variable you save 6 calls, i.e. 18 matrix multiplications including a total of (if I count correctly) 78 trigonometric function calls. *Mathematica* might remember some of the results making it probably less costly than that, but anyway.

Comment: @mikuszefski I've taken care of that in my code by using memoization.

Comment: OK, didn't notice this; I understand that cleaning up the code, is not the main goal here.

Comment: @mikuszefski I believe it's much better and faster now

Comment: No doubt about that. I guess you should mention the "memoization" in the answer more explicit than "some tricks".

Comment: @mikuszefski  Done, you're right

Comment: Like the `RotationMatrix` and the `Reduce` solution. With similar modifications I got (on my machine) a speed up from 15000 sec down to 900 sec, i.e. a factor of about 16 - nice. (@Alexander) Without constraints, however, it is well below 1 min, with reasonable values for `b` and `c`, but `Rphe>2000`.

Comment: Finally a general comment on fitting. Fitting is usually more robust and converging better if the parameter space is mainly orthogonal and the space to search of the same order of magnitude in every direction. The first part is usually difficult to control (although sometimes a nice coordinate transformation exists), for the second part one would set ` -1 < b < 1 && -1 < c < 1 && 4 < Rphe < 5` and call `Rfit[0.1 b, 0.1  c, Ang, Hamp, 100 Rphe]`. That seems a little bit ridiculous, but it really helps sometimes and can even speed up conversion.